Different method behaviour for different data trait impls
I have a struct which holds three vectors with different types:
pub struct ElementStorage {
    resistors: Vec<Resistor>,
    capacitors: Vec<Capacitor>,
    inductors: Vec<Inductor>,
}

Resistor, Capacitor and Inductor are a part of Element trait.
Now I want to create function ElementStorage::add_element<T: Element>(...) which would push the element to the correct vector. Is that possible?
I have tried with ElementStorage::add_element(element: &dyn Element) but I would prefer using static dispatch for greater performance.

If you want to avoid any runtime cost then you can implement conversion to an enum type representing the possible element types and then bound on that conversion.  For example:
pub enum ElementType {
    Resistor(Resistor),
    Capacitor(Capacitor),
    Inductor(Inductor),
}

impl From<Resistor> for ElementType {
    fn from(v: Resistor) -> ElementType {
        ElementType::Resistor(v)
    }
}

impl From<Capacitor> for ElementType {
    fn from(v: Capacitor) -> ElementType {
        ElementType::Capacitor(v)
    }
}

impl From<Inductor> for ElementType {
    fn from(v: Inductor) -> ElementType {
        ElementType::Inductor(v)
    }
}

With this, you can implement ElementStorage::add_element like so:
impl ElementStorage {
    pub fn add_element(&mut self, element: impl Into<ElementType>) {
        match element.into() {
            ElementType::Resistor(v) => self.resistors.push(v),
            ElementType::Capacitor(v) => self.capacitors.push(v),
            ElementType::Inductor(v) => self.inductors.push(v),
        }
    }
}

There should not be any runtime cost; the optimizer can trivially inline the into() invocation and will realize that two of the match arms are dead.  Ultimately, the assembly should wind up being identical to directly invoking push on the relevant Vec.  (It was in my tests even at optimization level 1.)

Though I'd probably prefer @cdhowie's answer (because you might find yourself needing that ElementType type down the line anyway), for completeness' sake here's another way to do it by making the ability to add an Element of a given type the trait and implementing it for ElementStorage:
pub trait AddElement<T> {
    fn add_element(&mut self, element: T);
}

impl AddElement<Resistor> for ElementStorage {
    fn add_element(&mut self, element: Resistor) {
        self.resistors.push(element);
    }
}

impl AddElement<Capacitor> for ElementStorage {
    fn add_element(&mut self, element: Capacitor) {
        self.capacitors.push(element);
    }
}

impl AddElement<Inductor> for ElementStorage {
    fn add_element(&mut self, element: Inductor) {
        self.inductors.push(element);
    }
}

One downside here is that clients need to import the AddElmement trait in order to call the add_element method on ElementStorage.
